# My iCloud storage was not updated to 50GB

Tags: icloud

So far I had iCloud Storage `20GB`. But since Apple changed their storage, I should have `50GB`, but there is still 20. Why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you purchased a monthly plan before September 16, 2015, your
>   account was upgraded automatically. If you're currently on an annual
>   plan, you'll continue to renew annually at that rate. If you select a
>   new monthly plan, your annual plan won't be available to you.

Source : https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201238

Comment: Don't understand. I purchased monthly plan before September 16, 2015, but my account was not upgraded automatically. Current plan is ok, but real storage is not ok.

Comment: I think you'll have to wait until the end of the current month (september),  it will change automatically at the beginning of the next billing cycle (first of october). This is just an assumption you need to contact Apple , they're the only ones who'll have the exact information.

Comment: I think you are right, I wait...:) thx

Comment: I'm happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Apple after a few days:

> We recently updated our iCloud storage plans and have increased your storage from 20GB to 50GB - at no additional cost. We increased iCloud storage so you can get even more out of services like iCloud Photo Library and iCloud Drive.
>
> Your storage plan will automatically renew at 50GB on your current renewal date and your credit card on file will be charged 0,99 € each month until you change or cancel your plan.
>
> The iCloud Team

Answer (score 0):

I pay annually (not month-to-month), and had patiently waited until my Oct. 7th renewal date for the upgrade to take place. It never did.  I finally called today, and found out the free upgrade is only for month-to-month plans, NOT annual plans! :(